# Cant enable the fluid mesh even after baking

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh, particles, baking

i tried the fluid simulation but it is only showing particles, i even enabled the mesh option and baked the data but cant see the fluid mesh.[image]

Comment: You need to change the Bake Type from Modular to All.

Comment: i think they removed the all option in newer versions. It is now final. In most of youtube videos mesh is working in modular also.

Comment: In 2.93.4, the option is still there.  However, if you leave it as modular, you need to select mesh, do the modular bake, and then in the mesh subpanel bake the mesh after you bake the particles